# SageOne refresh token api error - DataParsingError

Tags: api, sage-one

I am facing the strange issue, same code that we implemented is working fine on one system but giving issue on another system. Getting this error -

**{"$severity":"error","$dataCode":"DataParsingError","$message":"The data you sent could not be processed.","$source":"Proxy"}**

Let me know please why am I facing this issue on one system but working on another.
Following this documentation - https://qa-developer-portal-home.sageaccountantscloud.com/accounting/guides/authentication/

EndPoint - https://oauth.accounting.sage.com/token

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth.accounting.sage.com

client_id=4b64axxxxxxxxxx00710&
client_secret=iNumzTxxxxxxxxxxhVHstrqWesH8tm9&
grant_type=refresh_token&
refresh_token=b06b13xxxxxa275f08bfb57a3
```

Comment: You are using a very old version of the documentation in the staging environment. The actual documentation is https://developer.sage.com/api/accounting/guides/authentication/

Comment: Both are having the same code to refresh token

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to refresh a token you received via API v3 with the OAuth service from API v3.1, where moved to a different technology in the backend.

When you use a client registered at https://developerselfservice.sageone.com/ you will automatically get tokens for API v3.1.

Also, you are using a quite outdated version of the documentation, which really shouldn't be online anymore. Please refer to the documentation at https://developer.sage.com/api/accounting/guides/authentication/

Comment: Both documentations are having the same end point and request data kindly check "Renew an Access Token"

Answer (score 0):

I was sending wrong refresh token. Due to which I was getting this issue of "DataParsingError"